# Is it necessary to unbind events from elements removed from a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

I am using JQuery, and I would like to know if the remove() method cleans its contents of event handlers. For instance:

```
function someFunction() {
    var element = $('<div></div>');
    element.click(function() {
        alert('bar');
    });
    $('body').append(element);
    element.remove();
}
```

At this point is there an event handler still hanging out in memory? If so, is there a way to clear the element object of event handlers before removing it from the DOM?

Comment: IIf there is an issue, it should be fixed with jQuery, instead of in hodge-podge accessory code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> In addition to the elements themselves, *all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed*.

Comment: I must have missed that. Thank you.

Comment: But it will **only** remove those added using jQuery, it doesn't know about any others.